# linux user login/logout log for computer restriction

Tags: linux, bash, time, authentication

I would like to know how to log the login and logout of a user : it would be a mean to measure how much time someone has been connected in a month so far.

I know it's possible to use the command "last". But this command is based on a file that has a r/w permission for the user, hence the possibility to change these data.
I would like to log these data over two months.

Why would I like to do that ? In fact, I would like to prevent a normal user to use a computer (in graphical mode mainly) more than an hour a day - except week-ends, and 10 hours in total a week.

Cedric

(System used : kubuntu,/ Programming language : bash script)

Comment: No, belongs on superuser. By the way, `/var/log/wtmp` is writable by root and members of utmp. It shouldn't be writable by an ordinary user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for, but [this article](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/linux/soa/Restrict-users-access-on-Linux-systems/0,339028299,339284240,00.htm) shows how to restrict a user from only being able to login during the specified time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer/comments. I will have a further look at linux PAM, and if I can't find information there, I will pay more attention to 'last' as /var/log/wtmp shouldn't be writable by an ordinay user.
And last but not least, I'll pay mind the site I will post my question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl script which summarises the content printed by `last`. It's based on an example from the book [Running Linux](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002725), cleaned up for readability and corrected to work on a modern machine (the format of `last's` output seems to have changed since the original was written). Save the code to a file, and you can then run it by piping the output of `last` to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

# logintime.pl - Summarise amount of time a user is logged in.
# Usage: last | perl logintime.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hours;
my %minutes;
my %logins;

# While we have input...
while ( <> ) {

  # Extract the username and login time...
  if ( my ($username, $hrs, $mins) = /^(\S+).*\((\d+):(\d+)\)/ ) {
    # Increment total hours, minutes, and logins 
    $hours{$username}   += $hrs; 
    $minutes{$username} += $mins; 
    $logins{$username}++;
  } 
} 

# For each unique user...
foreach my $user ( sort keys %hours ) { 
   # Calculate the total hours and minutes...
   $hours{$user}   += int($minutes{$user} / 60); 
   $minutes{$user} %= 60;

   # Print the information for this user...
   print "User $user, total login time "; 
   printf "%02d:%02d, ", $hours{$user}, $minutes{$user}; 
   print "total logins $logins{$user}.\n"; 
}
```